# WPF DataGridCheckBoxColumn check/uncheck sometimes don't work

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGridCheckBox` column bound to a field in DB.
The issue is that sometimes the check/uncheck works right away, and sometimes
it doesn't, even if I click many times, the click won't stay.
In these cases, the only thing that solves this is clicking the CheckBox,
and while **mouse down**, dragging to next field and leave mouse.
This way the checked/uncheck stays fine...

This is the code:

```
DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="to_send" Binding="{Binding to_send, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="150" Header="האם לשלוח" IsThreeState="False" ElementStyle="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}"
```

What am I doing wrong ?

I've tried it with DataGridTemplateColumn - Still same problem......

Thanks,
Ronit.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong.

Try this

```
DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="to_send" 
IsChecked="{Binding to_send, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
Width="150" Header="האם לשלוח" IsThreeState="False" 
ElementStyle="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}"
```

Comment: Use IsChecked Tag instead of Binding Tag. Rest of the code is same.

Comment: For what you suggested here I'd need to change the DataGridCheckBoxColumn  to DataGridTemplateColumn and add
DataTemplate and inside it a CheckBox tag with the IsChecked property.
Is there any way to do this with DataGridCheckBoxColumn  ?

Comment: IsChecked doesn't exist

Comment: @Ronitba I know it's too late but just add UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged it will fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me (add UpdateSourceTrigger) :

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn
                        Binding="{Binding Path=IsRequired, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        Header="Required"
                        IsThreeState="False" />
```